# Missing product data on Magento reports (bestseller, products ordered) although in database

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, reports

Yesterday I ran a modified XML export at the `Sales -> Orders` overview. During this process there was an error and now I have a reporting issue:

My reports seem to be reset and all information prior to the export appears to be missing.

However, everything works fine with the reports in the interval **after** the incident, so no unusual behaviour - topsellers etc. are shown like you would expect them to.

The following reports are affected (not a complete list):

1. `Reports -> Products -> Bestsellers`
2. `Reports -> Products -> Products Ordered`
3. `Reports -> Customers -> Customers by Orders Total`
4. `Reports -> Sales -> Tax`

However, for example this report works fine:

- Reports -> Shopping Cart -> [any]

When going to `Sales -> Orders` I have a complete list of all sales ever done in the shop. Whichever order I open, there is all the required information available (e.g. products bought, subtotal, date etc.).

I read that the

> Reports -> Products -> Bestsellers

table is based on the `sales_flat_order_item` & `sales_flat_order` table. I checked these, all entries up to the first day of the shop are there.

As far as I can tell, all shop history is available and no data has been deleted. I also tried `Reports -> Refresh statistics` (lifetime) but it had no effect.

Does anybody know where else to look or what to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some database examination I discovered that in the table `sales_flat_order_item` the column "state" had Null everywhere whereas the column "status" was fine and had the right information.

I updated the table via SQL

> SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` UPDATE `sales_flat_order` SET `state`
>   = "processing" WHERE `state` is Null

and refresehd the lifetime statistics in the backend (`reports -> update statistics`) and the reports now show everything correctly once more.